# ¿Como cambiar de componente dinámicamente en react?

Tags: reactjs

Hola soy nuevo en reactjs, estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto con esta tecnología y me surgió una duda y no tengo idea de cómo implementar esto, se trata de cambiar un componente por otro al darle click, gracias de ante mano por sus respuestas

Comment: No se si entendí bien la pregunta, pero si lo que deseas es navegar entre componentes revisa [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con cambiar un component por otro? Si es literalmente eso, tener un componente y después de alguna acción cambiarlo por otro diferente, puedes hacerlo con un simple `if...else` y una variable en el estado que te indique qué componente debe estar visible en cada momento. Al cambiar la variable de estado, el componente se renderizará de nuevo y en lugar de aparecer uno será otro (dependiendo del `if...else`). Por favor, añade más detalles para poder darte una solución más concreta. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.